# Weird sound coming from the engine when started and also moving

Tags: honda, noise, odyssey

I have an Honda Odyssey 2007 model. I hear weird noise as if there is no exhaust but that sound is coming from the engine. I hear the noise when I start and also when the car moves, but sometimes I feel that I hear no such noise when the speed is more than 60 mph when my foot is on the accelerator. Please let me know what is the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be many things. Unfortunately, you have given little detail which makes it impossible to tell you exactly what the problem is.

But from what you describe, it sounds like you have an exhaust leak. This could be a damaged pipe or failed gasket. It would be best to take it to a mechanic to have it inspected.